# Getting rid of limited RGB range with HDMI and Nvidia graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi

I have two monitors, both connected to a Nvidia RTX 2060 graphic card, one with a DVI and one with a HDMI cable.

Monitor 1 with DVI has a perfectly clear screen, Monitor 2 with HDMI has a blue tint and "washed out" colors. After switching cables, Monitor 1 with HDMI has blue tint and washed out colors, while Monitor 2 with DVI has a clear screen.

So it seems, that the limited RGB range (usually for TVs) is the cause. In the Nvidia system panel, the monitor connected with HDMI has a resolution listed under "Ultra-HD, HD, SD", while the DVI connected monitor is listed under "PC". This indicates, that the monitor is detected as "TV-like" device and so, the limited RGB range is used.

However, I already installed the lates Nvidia driver (431.70) and tried different options for the resolution in the Nvidia system panel, including:

- Setting color format to "RGB" and dynamic range to "full" (instead of "limited")
- Setting color format to "YCbCr422"
- Setting color format to "YCbCr444"
- Setting a non-native resolution, that is listed under "PC" instead of "Ultra-HD, HD, SD"

All these settings were also followed by a restart of the PC and turning monitors off and on again.

I also checked already brightness/gamma/etc. of different RGB channels and also tried to reset them to default.

System is Windows 10 Pro, Monitor 1 is a iiyama ProLite E2273HDS, Monitor 2 is a iiyama ProLite E2481HS-B1.

**Problem**: Unfortunatly, nothing so far helped: no matter which setting or which monitor, if connected via HDMI, the colors look bad. If connected via DVI, everything looks great. Unfortunatly, the graphic card has only one DVI port.

**Question**: How can I fix this problem? In principle, HDMI should be able to give the same display quality as DVI, so it should be possible somehow, right?

Comment: Have you tried a different HDMI cable?

Comment: @Andy No, atm I have only this cable... If I buy a new one, is there something to take care about? However, I think the problem is software related..

Comment: Well I've never heard of HDMI having a "limited RGB range," and even if true there shouldn't be a noticeable blue tint in the image regardless.

Comment: @Andy Its not that HDMI has a limited RGB range, its that TVs do (as I wrote). Actually it is a well known problem and one of the main reasons that they implemented the "full RGB" option in the Nvidia driver in the first place. However, it seems it still isn't working reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a possible solution for anyone who stumbles across this thread:

I had the same issue - DVI & DisplayPort looked fine, but HDMI was washed out. It turns out the HDMI RGB setting on my **monitor** was set to 'limited' 16~235 range, even though the source from my PC was putting out full range RGB.

After hunting through the monitor menu I came across a setting for HDMI RGB, and once set to full range, the picture matches the other inputs. Hope this helps someone!